# How to make a change in the_geom_webmercator visible in the_geom in CartoDB?

Tags: postgresql, carto

I am having some trouble with the the_geom column and the the_geom_webmercator column in CartoDB. I have some SQL (which I modified from http://bl.ocks.org/andrewxhill/8695515) in which the the_geom_webmercator column is changed, but the the_geom column is not changed. This means that the changes to latitude and longitude which are visible in the map are not visible in the data, which is a problem. Below is the SQL:

```
with q AS (
  SELECT cartodb_id, the_geom_webmercator
  FROM untitled_table_7
  WHERE name= 'Rome'),
             m AS (
               SELECT count(*) n,
               array_agg(cartodb_id) id_list, the_geom_webmercator
               FROM q
               GROUP BY the_geom_webmercator),
             f AS (
               SELECT  n, generate_series(1, array_length(id_list,1)) p, unnest(id_list) cartodb_id, the_geom_webmercator
               FROM m),
              a AS (
             SELECT ST_SetSRID(
               ST_MakePoint(
                 ST_X(f.the_geom_webmercator) + f.p * 180 * cos(f.p * radians(301*ceil(f.n/20.0))/f.n), ST_Y(f.the_geom_webmercator) + f.p*180 * sin(f.p * radians(301*ceil(f.n/20.0))/f.n)),3857) the_geom_webmercator, f.cartodb_id
FROM f, untitled_table_7 t)
UPDATE untitled_table_7
SET the_geom_webmercator = a.the_geom_webmercator
FROM a
WHERE untitled_table_7.cartodb_id = a.cartodb_id
```

How can I adapt this so that the changes in the the_geom_webmercator column are shown in the the_geom column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could transform `the_geom_webmercator`, which is in Web Mercator (SRID = 3857) to the projection of `the_geom`, which is WGS84 (SRID = 4326). All you have to do is replace the row that has `SET the_geom_webmercator = a.the_geom_webmercator` with this:

```
SET the_geom = ST_Transform(a.the_geom_webmercator,4326)
```

Once `the_geom` is set, it will trigger `the_geom_webmercator` to be projected from that.

Read more about projections in CartoDB in [this tutorial](http://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/projections.html).